# Indesign: First line doesn't start at the top

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, grids

For some reason, the first line of my design doesn't start at the top but leaves a small space between top margin and first word. 
The paragraph style is:

- Size: `95pt`
- Leading: `72pt`
- `Align to baseline grid`

And the Grid increment setting is `12pt`

[image: go to the top please]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have the wrong *First Baseline Offset* setting for this situation.

- Select the text frame and open *Text Frame Options* using <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>.
- Switch to the *Baseline Options* tab:

  [image]

  The *First Baseline > Offset* specifies the vertical position of the first baseline of the text frame. You probably have it set to *Ascent* which is the default value. As you see there are five possibilities:

  [image]

  *Ascent*, *Cap Height* and *x Height* uses info found in the font file. *Leading* uses the leading of the text. *Fixed* allows for any custom position on or below the top edge of the frame.
- In your case, to allow the text to start closer to the top edge, you should try *Cap Height* or *x Height* depending on what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Select the text frame and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> Win to open the **Text Frame Options** and at the **Vertical Justification** pop up menu select **Top**

Comment: Already set on Top