# To align line at the bottom of its line spacing

Tags: adobe-indesign

The font size is 12 pt, tracking (aka line spacing) is 18 pt, and 18 pt between guides:

[image]

I want the lines to be aligned at the bottom of their line spacing instead of their top. What is the proper way to do this?

Do I need to shift the baseline (that is, to open the basic paragrah settings, select "Advanced Character Formats", and then adjust "Baseline Shift" to `-6 pt`) or there is a better way?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to manually add guides for this. InDesign has a built-in feature for this called **Baseline Grid**. Here is a quick intro to it.

If you enter *Edit > Preferences > Grid* you can set up the baseline grid as you like. In your case something like this:

[image]

Turn on the baseline grid using *View > Grids & Guides > Show Baseline Grid*.

Now you have the grid set up, but the text won't automatically align to it:

[image]

The simple way of forcing text to align to the grid is simply entering its *Paragraph Style Options* and set *Indents and Spacing > Align to Grid* to *All Lines*:

[image]

Now any line of texct using this paragraph style will be forced to align to the baseline grid:

[image]

---

In your specific case there is also a simpler way to control where the first line of a text frame begins.

Enter the text frame's *Text Frame Options* and set *Baseline Options > First Baseline > Offset* to *Leading*.

[image]

This way, the first baseline of the text frame will be 18 pt. below the top of the text frame.

Read more about this issue in [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/125504).

Comment: Btw: You use the word "tracking" where you really mean "leading" = "line spacing". "Tracking" is the distance between letters.